# Could not cast value of type 'MyAppName.ProfileController' to 'MyAppName.SelectController'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewController with 3 buttons and a stepper

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class HomeController: UIViewController {
    var steppers : UIStepper?

    static var globalLimit: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc : SelectController = (segue.destination as? SelectController)! {
            vc.limit = Int(stepper.value)
            HomeController.globalLimit = Int(stepper.value)
        }
        if let np = segue.destination as? CourseController {
            np.numberPlaces = Int(stepper.value)
        }
    }
```

and my application is crashing here:

```
if let vc : SelectController = (segue.destination as? SelectController)!
```

with the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'MyAppName.ProfileController'  to 'MyAppName.SelectController'

After, when I press a button that is not the SelectTapped button (in this case I had pressed the profile button). What's the cause of the problem? How can I solve it? I expect that it is necessary to use the `static var globalLimit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are force casting and that produces the error. Change the method like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let vc = segue.destination as? SelectController {
        vc.limit = Int(stepper.value)
        HomeController.globalLimit = Int(stepper.value)
    }
    if let np = segue.destination as? CourseController {
        np.numberPlaces = Int(stepper.value)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message carefully. It says: The actual controller (`segue.destination`) is of type `ProfileController` which is not related to proposed `SelectController`.

When performing **multiple** segues in **one** controller the most reliable solution is to switch on the `identifier`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "goToCourseController":

        let courseController = segue.destination as! CourseController
        courseController.numberPlaces = Int(stepper.value)

    case "goToSelectController": 

        let selectController = segue.destination as! SelectController
        selectController.limit = Int(stepper.value)
        HomeController.globalLimit = Int(stepper.value)

    case "goToProfileController":

        let profileController = segue.destination as! ProfileController
        // do something with profileController

    default: break      
    }
}
```

In this case the forced unwrapped optionals will reveal a **design error** if the code crashes.

**Note:**

In Swift 4 the `identifier` has its own namespace which helps to make the code still more reliable.